# Dynamically adding a Button to a PlaceHolder in a DataGrid

Tags: asp.net

I have basically something like this:

```
<asp:datagrid id="DGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Stuff">
    <ItemTemplate> 
      <asp:PlaceHolder id="PH" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateColumn>
</asp:datagrid>
```

I need to add a Button to the PlaceHolder depending on the values of the data I am binding. At the moment I am adding the Button after the data is bound in Page_Load. The problem is that the data binding methods are not called in postbacks, so the Button disappears when I click on it.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Problem is that I need to know some attributes of the grid item to create the Button, so I cannot create it before the data has been bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about subscribing to [ItemCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemcreated.aspx) event?

Markup:

```
<asp:datagrid id="DGrid" runat="server" OnItemCreated="DGrid_ItemCreated" AutoGenerateColumns="false">...</asp:DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void DGrid_ItemCreated(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    var ph e.Item.FindControl("PH") as PlaceHolder;
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding the situation when the `e.Item.DataItem` is `null` on a postback: only the reliable information (e.g. databound control properties) is persisted across postbacks (if ViewState is enabled), the entire data items don't survive them. Therefore you have to manage the state by yourself. You can persist only the necessary data in a ViewState (and not the entire data items since it can blow it up).

Comment: I still need to somehow access the bound data in postback - e.Item.DataItem seems to be NULL by then.

Comment: Usually e.Item.DataItem is null not because of a viewstate issue but because you are rendering the header or footer rows.  Try doing a if(e.Item.DataItem is nothing) { return;} and see what happens.

Comment: @Patricker: yes, you're right, but I don't think it's the case here... Or? ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it working. Now I basically persist a few needed values to the ViewState so I can create the buttons in `ItemCreated` the same way when postback happens.